# How to connect and Authenticate Wordpress Woo commerce API with Mobile app

Tags: flutter, authentication, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to provide an API endpoint to a mobile developer and I'm confused with woocommerce concept with how to use their API by generating consumer key and consumer secret those credentials need to be sent with each request to authenticate the request, what I don't understand and I can't feel right about it, is that those credentials will be used for all users who are using the app without consumer key and consumer secret I can't access any endpoint, they give the feeling that those Endpoints and this way of authenticating not aimed for such a purpose only for developing extensions and admin area extension related to woocommerce not any way to a front end area. What is the right way to use and authenticate woocommerce API to the mobile app?

I tried to use as many plugins available as JWT to provide JSON authentication also I tried to make my endpoints as custom endpoints but still don't understand it I don't understand how to use it like what to provide for mobile developers how to register a customer?